# Prevent Bootstrap Modal from Disabling Rest of Page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

An open bootstrap modal seems to disable any interactions such as clicking, dragging etc. on the rest of the page.

How can I change this behavior such as to allow such interactions?

With jquery-ui this would be accomplished by setting the `modal` option to `false`.

Comment: What are you using it for? Seems like a UX question more than anything.

Comment: I want users to be able to drag stuff from the page and drop them on to the modal; not a UX issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bootstrap 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/486/

Add this attributes: `role="menu" data-backdrop="false"` to `class="modal`

for example:

`<div id="myModal1" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="menu" data-backdrop="false">`

**bootstrap 3**

http://jsfiddle.net/hc1yebkx/3/

use css:

```
.modal {
   height:auto; bottom:auto;
   width: 400px;
   margin-left: 200px;/* half of the additional width.*/    
}
```

Comment: You're using bootstrap 2; when I use your fiddle with v3; the modal won't even open.

Comment: I added a solution for bootstrap 3

Comment: I'm now able to drag items on the rest of the page. However, I'd like to be able to drag them onto the modal. Currently, an element goes invisible as soon as it moves over the modal.

Comment: I'm now able to drag items on the page, but I'd like to be able to drag them onto the modal. Currently, they go invisible as soon as the go over the modal.

Comment: I accomplished this by changing the `z-index` of the draggable element.